# Swift Xcode 6 baseball Counter

Tags: ios, swift

I can't seem to write the if statement in the end to make the outs go up when the strikes hit 3?
can someone lease help and make it so in swift the outs will go up when someone hits 3 strikes

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  helloWordDemo
//
//  Created by Developer on 6/8/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AECApps. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBOutlet var labelDispaly : UILabel = nil
// dispaly Strikes

var counter = 1

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

    labelDispaly.text = "Strikes \(counter++)"
}
//button to add strikes

@IBOutlet var OutsDispaly : UILabel = nil

var outsCounter = 1
//outs dispaly

@IBAction func outsButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

    OutsDispaly.text = "Outs \(outsCounter++)"

}
//button to add outs
if counter = 3 {
    outsCounter ++
   }
}
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `=` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a property observer:

```
var counter = 1 {
didSet {
    if counter == 3 {
        self.outsCounter++
    }
}
}
```

Whenever counter gets changed, didSet will be called.

(Also note that the equality operator is `==`. `=` is for assignment.)